# How to apply lrtemplates, DNG, XMP to images using python?

Tags: python-3.x, image, xmp, colormatrix, dng

As I researched, popular images presets are lrtemplates, dng, xmp.
However, we can only apply those filters by professional softwares like Photoshop, Lightroom, etc.
Is it possible to do it by code (especially Python)? The idea is to develop a server which allow users to upload their image, choose a filter and apply to the images.
I found a way to apply filters by color matrix here: https://fecolormatrix.com/.
But I'm looking for more resources on the internet, where mostly not in color matrix, but in above extension. If possible, it's best to convert those extension into color matrix.

Thank you in advance!